# QGIS Broken Link to files on a server

Tags: qgis, network

My colleagues and I are using different versions of QGIS (2.8.2, 2.86 & 2.14) on windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

When we open existing projects we get a "Handle Bad Layers" box coming up. We have each tried to reset the datasource link and when we do this we get a message saying "The specified network name is no longer available."

When we copy & paste the shapefiles onto our C drive we can open them in the project. After doing this, the original file path then seems to work but is lost again when the project is closed down & reopened.

We have referred this to our company IT consultant who has advise it is a QGIS problem and not a server problem.

I also have projects & shapefiles on Dropbox and these work fine. Can anyone clarify if this is a QGIS problem or a server problem?

Comment: By default QGIS stores relative paths. So in relation to the project file. What is the folder structure of your projects? Are the projects stored in the same folder tree as the data?

Comment: Yes, the projects file and shapefiles are all stored in the same folder.

Comment: Have you changed the project to store absolute paths?

Comment: I've just saved the project with absolute paths and then tried to add the shapefiles again but it has given me the same error message that the specified network name is no longer available.